# как обойти ошибку "отношение "webface.v_google_fines_info1" не существует"

Tags: django, postgresql

Во вьюшке есть запрос к БД:

```
fine = VgoogleFinesInfo.objects.all()
```

Модель:

```
class VgoogleFinesInfo(models.Model):

    Поля ...
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '"webface"."v_google_fines_info1"'
```

И возникает ошибка:

```
отношение "webface.v_google_fines_info1" не существует
LINE 1: ..."webface"."v_google_fines_info1"."column_12" FROM "webface"....
```

Как обойти эту ошибку?(мне нужно её именно обойти, а не исправить(да)) мне нужно, если она возникает, то запрос выглядел так:

```
fine = []
```

вместо

```
fine = VgoogleFinesInfo.objects.all()
```

(try/catch не помогает)